# Linux memory mapped files (deleted)

Tags: linux, memory-management, solr, cassandra, mmap

I have a question regarding mmap files in Linux (Ubuntu 14 to be specific).

We are running DSE/DSE SOLR on a host and we are seeing some files disappear randomly. It looks like when the application starts building an index it creates a bunch of mmap files and uses them as it continues building it's indexes. Looking in /proc/${dse_pid}/map_files I see a bunch of symlinks that point to (deleted) files. In our logs we're seeing stuff like

> ERROR [http-8983-exec-5] 2017-04-20 02:08:41,901 SolrException.java
>   (line 136) IO error while trying to get the size of the
>   Directory:java.io.FileNotFoundException: _2zm29_Lucene41_0.pos

An example of what the map_files look like is this:

> lr-------- 1 cassandra cassandra 64 Apr 21 16:49
>   7f82c1a22000-7f82c1a23000 ->
>   /cassandra/data/solr.data/clearcore_solr.validations_search/index/_2grig_BloomFilter_0.tim
>   (deleted) lr-------- 1 cassandra cassandra 64 Apr 21 16:49
>   7f82c1a23000-7f82c1a24000 ->
>   /cassandra/data/solr.data/clearcore_solr.validations_search/index/_2grig_BloomFilter_0.pos
>   (deleted) lr-------- 1 cassandra cassandra 64 Apr 21 16:49
>   7f82c1a24000-7f82c1a25000 ->
>   /cassandra/data/solr.data/clearcore_solr.validations_search/index/_2grig_BloomFilter_0.doc
>   (deleted) lr-------- 1 cassandra cassandra 64 Apr 21 16:49
>   7f82c1a25000-7f82c1a28000 ->
>   /cassandra/data/solr.data/clearcore_solr.validations_search/index/_2grig_Lucene41_0.pos
>   (deleted) lr-------- 1 cassandra cassandra 64 Apr 21 16:49
>   7f82c1a29000-7f82c1a2a000 ->
>   /cassandra/data/solr.data/clearcore_solr.validations_search/index/_2grig.nvd
>   (deleted) lr-------- 1 cassandra cassandra 64 Apr 21 16:49
>   7f82c1a2a000-7f82c1a2b000 ->
>   /cassandra/data/solr.data/clearcore_solr.validations_search/index/_2grig_Lucene41_0.doc
>   (deleted)

My question is, is there anything that could cause these files to randomly disappear? It seems like it's one or two files every few days that dse logs this type of error, there are about 90 total (deleted) links in proc/. Could the OS be cleaning up some of these mmap files prematurely and thus the symlinks in proc/ become broken? I'm at a loss explaining this behaviour.

Additionally with mmap files in general, if a process doesn't properly close its connection to the mmap file, does the OS cleanup the file and remove it from the filesystem? Or what occurs if a process doesn't cleanly break it's connection to the file?

Answer (score 0):

Solr uses large amounts of Java heap, and also large mmap files. If it gets to the point of consuming all physical RAM you will see a dramatic slowdown, but still no failure.

Solr's mmap files are ephemeral. You could investigate why DSE would want to keep symbolic links to Solr's mmap files. But if there is no functional DSE problem, then perhaps this all does not matter.